# Ошибка с findViewById в AndroidStudio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

В чём заключается ошибка? Прошу помощи

Вот Скриншот человека, у которого нет ошибки:
[image: Скриншот человека, у которого нет ошибки]

А это мой Скриншот с ошибкой:
[image: Мой скриншот с ошибкой]

В любом случае я пробовал все методы, но что-то ничего не помогает(

Это мой код, не правильный. Мне нужно вывести в текстовом варианте.

```
  override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        mData?.let {
            val coin = it[position]
            holder.view.findViewById(R.id.tvSymbol) = coin.symbol
        }
```

Это ТекстВью который мне надо вывести:

```
  TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvSymbol"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        tools:text="BTC"
```

Это Холдер:

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
    return MyViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_coin, parent, false))
}
```

Вот сам класс:

```
package com.example.cryptodopingapp.components

import android.view.View
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

class MyViewHolder(val view: View):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Текст кода покажите, скриншоты невидно

Comment: Вы перед ```= coin.symbol``` забыли `.text`. Поясню. Вы пытаетесь присвоить переменной типа `TextView` текст. На самом деле Вам нужно его присвоить свойству `text` той самой переменной `TextView`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так должен выглядеть ваш холдер:

```kotlin
class MyViewHolder(val view: View):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    // все используемые вью объявляем и находим здесь
    val tvSymbol: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvSymbol)
}
```

Вот так использоваться:

```kotlin
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
    mData?.let {
        val coin = it[position]
        holder.tvSymbol.text = coin.symbol
    }
}
```

Comment: а ещё вопрос, текстовое значение это text, а мне нужно числовое, которое double, как оно пишется? или просто вписать в конце ToString?

Comment: `TextView` умеет отображать текст - для отображения чего-либо другого, оно должно быть преобразовано в текст. Я плохо знаю котлин - как там правильно преобразовать число в строку смотрите документацию